# ¿Como modificar una clave foranea de otra tabla con un update sin modificar los criterios de la tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas una departamento con direccion nombre y numero y otra persona con nombre numero y id. quiero hacer un update para cambiar todas laas personas de la tabla cuyo departamento sea 3 por ejemplo. 
yo hago esto

```
uPDATE `persona` SET `numDepartamento`= '3' WHERE numDepartamento = 1
```

pero me da este

```
error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`persona`, CONSTRAINT `persona_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`numDepartamento`) REFERENCES `departamento` (`numDepto`))
```

Comment: Podrías subir la estructura de las dos tablas?

Comment: @Juan clave primaria de departamento numero de departamento y tiene direccion y nombre. de persona Clave ajena numero de departamento clave primaria la ID y tiene un nombre

Comment: Departamento -> numDepartamento(PK), direccion,nombre  // Persona-> ID(PK), nombre, numeroDepartamento(FK) .  ¿Asi?

Comment: si asi exactamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es algo común hacerlo, por algo existen las FK para no violentar la estructura de la base de datos... pero se puede hacer, intenta lo siguiente

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `persona` SET `numDepartamento`= '3' WHERE numDepartamento = 1
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Claro, las deshabilitas, forzas el cambio y dsp las volves a habilitar.

Comment: Cosas de mi profesor yo solo me ataño a lo que el pide

Comment: como seria eso ponerlo en query? igual?

Comment: Si, igual, pero separas por `;` para que se ejecute cada línea. O manual, ejecutar primero una luego otra y luego la otra.

Comment: Recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta marcarla como correcta.